# Problems with bonding on 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-bonding

The system runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with 3 1GBit NICs: one embedded and 2 Intel PCIe NICs. Both Intel NICs are bonded (bond0) with mode 4 (LACP). The switch is confugured to support LACP on these 2 ports. Here is the network configuration:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s31f6
#iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
    mtu 9000
    address 192.168.x.x
    netmask 255.255.x.0
    network 192.168.x.0
    gateway 192.168.x.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.x.x

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    mtu 9000
    address 192.168.x.x
    netmask 255.255.x.0
    network 192.168.x.0
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate 1
    bond-slaves none
```

This configuration runs rather well without errors. But if the network load is rather high (for instance, during copying 100-200 GB), the following errors are produced in /var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 14 17:20:02 ubuntu1 kernel: [29601.287684] e1000e: enp3s0 NIC Link is Down
Feb 14 17:20:02 ubuntu1 kernel: [29601.287993] e1000e 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: speed changed to 0 for port enp3s0
Feb 14 17:20:02 ubuntu1 kernel: [29601.379193] bond0: link status definitely down for interface enp3s0, disabling it
Feb 14 17:20:02 ubuntu1 kernel: [29601.379199] bond0: first active interface up!
Feb 14 17:20:04 ubuntu1 kernel: [29603.064712] e1000e: enp3s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Feb 14 17:20:04 ubuntu1 kernel: [29603.079162] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp3s0, 1000 Mbps full duplex
```

Is it a known problem? Apparently after some seconds the failed interface works well again. The problem doesn't occur very often.

In the file /proc/net/bonding/bond0 I can see, that the mode 4 was correctly recognized:

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: fast
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
```

I have tried to use bond-slaves with interface names instead of none. But in this case the ifenslave was locked during restarting of network services. So I have found a recommendation, that using "none" the bond0 will be up and doesn't lock.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding and maybe try changing the `bond-mode` to `bond-mode 4` and add both NICs to the `bond-slaves` line.  Did you also add `bonding` to the `/etc/modules` file?  These are only suggestions as unless we can duplicate your environment some answers can only be guesses.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to trace or diagnostic this problem?

Comment: Hmmmm, I am not 100% sure.  Most of the systems I have had to deal with doing Link-aggregation were on Red Hat servers.  However, I have seen that some of the Intel cards that use the e1000e you might have to get the network driver directly from Intel.  I have also seen switches be problems for us, but not very often.  What type of switch are you connecting to?

Comment: This is Linksys LGS326 26-Port Gigabit Smart Switch.

Comment: I have always been a huge fan of Linksys products.  The switch looks nice and has good setup pages on it.  Have you tried maybe setting the LACP on the ports of the switch to Dynamic or Static?

Comment: I was just reading its documentation to see if I could see anything about it:  http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/MAN_LGS308_LGS318_LGS326_LGS308P_LGS318P_LGS326P_8820-01844_RevC00_EN.pdf

Comment: At first I have used static LAG. Buit if the slave interface was down, the bonding interface was down as well and I have got an error during iSCSI access. So I have configured dynamic with LACP. In fact there are bonding errors in the syslog now, but the LACP is very fast and I have no errors in my application.

Comment: This one might be out of my realm of experience.  I have plenty of experience in setting up and configuring the `active-backup` bondings as with our servers it was more important.  Troubleshooting on those is simple as the port is either up or down and if the other port takes over instantly.  As the speeds picked up at my job and they went to 10Gb fibers and copper connections the LACP bondings went away.  One more thing is to maybe look at the ethernet driver used in the system from Intel.  Beyond that, I am so sorry that I am out of suggestions here.